# item with same key already exists

Tags: c#, list, linq, controller, viewmodel

Fairly new to LINQ and cannot understand why I am getting this error:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

I was thinking because I am using the select lambda expression 3 times? Otherwise, from the code, I cannot see how any property is being assigned more than once.  Is there any better way to write this and with explanation? Thanks.

Viewmodel:

```
public class AwardWinnersViewModel
{
    public int WinnerId { get; set; }
    public string AwardName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int JurisdictionRef { get; set; }
    public int WorkareaRef { get; set; }
    public string Jurisdiction { get; set; }
    public string Workarea { get; set; }
    public string LogoUrl { get; set; }

}

public class AwardWinnersWrapperVM
{
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<short, string>> JurisdictionFilter { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> WorkareaFilter { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AwardWinnersViewModel> AwardWinners { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int WinnersPerPage { get; set; }
    public bool HasPrevious { get; set; }
    public bool HasNext { get; set; }
    public int TotalWinners { get; set; } 
    public int? ResultsOutOf { get => (this.WinnersPerPage * (this.Page + 1)) < this.TotalWinners ? (this.WinnersPerPage * (this.Page + 1)) : this.TotalWinners; }
    public int NumberOfPips { get => this.TotalWinners / WinnersPerPage; }
    public int? SelectedJurisdiction { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedWorkarea { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? page, int? additionalJurisdictionSearch, int? additionalWorkareaSearch)
{
    var awardWinners = await awardWinnersService.GetAwardWinnersAsync();
    var jurisdictions = contentMetadataService.GetJurisdictions();
    var workareas = contentMetadataService.GetWorkareas();
    int pageNumber = page ?? 0;

    var viewModel = new AwardWinnersWrapperVM
    {
        TotalWinners = awardWinners.Count(),
        WinnersPerPage = winnersPerPage,
        Page = pageNumber,
        HasPrevious = pageNumber > 0,
        HasNext = awardWinners.Count() > (winnersPerPage * (pageNumber + 1)),

        AwardWinners = awardWinners.Select(x => new AwardWinnersViewModel
        {
            Type = x.Type,
            Contact = (x.Type == 1)
                ? x.WinnerId != 0 ? contributorService.GetContributor(x.WinnerId, true)?.DisplayName : string.Empty
                : x.WinnerId != 0 ? authorService.GetByRef(x.WinnerId, true)?.AuthorName : string.Empty,
            StartDate = x.StartDate,
            AwardName = x.AwardName,
            Jurisdiction = x.Jurisdiction,
            Workarea = x.Workarea,
            LogoUrl = (x.Type == 1)
                ? contributorService.GetContributor(x.WinnerId, true)?.LogoImageUrlCDN
                : authorService.GetByRef(x.WinnerId, true)?.PhotoUrl,
        }),
        JurisdictionFilter = awardWinners.Select(x => new { id = x.JurisdictionRef, display = (jurisdictions.TryGetValue((short)x.JurisdictionRef, out var jurisdiction) ? jurisdiction.JurisdictionName : string.Empty) }).ToDictionary(key => (short)key.id, val => val.display),
        WorkareaFilter = awardWinners.Select(x => new { id = x.WorkareaRef, display = (workareas.TryGetValue(x.WorkareaRef, out var workarea) ? workarea.WorkareaName : string.Empty) }).ToDictionary(key => key.id, val => val.display)
        .Skip(winnersPerPage * (pageNumber - 1))
        .Take(winnersPerPage)
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace on exception. I see a syntax error @ `PhotoUrl,` where you have an extra comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of your `awardWinners` share a `jurisdictionRef` or `workareaRef` then the `ToDictionary()` calls for `JurisdictionFilter` and `WorkareaFilter`will fail with that exception.

I think you want to grab only the distinct jurisdictions/workareas for your filter box (this can likely be achieved using `.Distinct()` immediately before the `ToDictionary`).